# send email in GCM onRegistered

Tags: android, email, android-intent, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I wont to send an email to a sever containing the Registration Id 
my code

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    Log.i("Registration", "Just registered!");

    Log.i("Registration", arg0.toString() + arg1.toString());   

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "example@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
    //     emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, CC.getText());

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

After running the code I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
    IntentService[GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-2]
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
    Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. 
    Is this really what you want?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open an email application in order to send the registration ID to your server, and even if it works the user of your app will have to send the email manually. I don't think that's what you want to do. You should send the regitration ID to your server without showing anything to the user. Why don't you send the registration ID to your server with an HTTP request?

As it is, your code doesn't work, and the error you got tells to the problem - you can't open an activity from outside an activity (in your case from a service), unless you start it in a new task.

Comment: thanks for answering , what do I need on the sever side to take the data . I have on the server a database and a C# program that is going to use this data